# How to write if statement inside template literals

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write some logical if else statement inside the javascript template literals. I am adding html code through innerHTML and based on some logic, change html to something otherwise to something else. Please consider here that, this is an example code and the real code could be different or bigger

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let x = 5;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    main.innerHTML = `
    <h2>First</h2>
        ${if(x > 3) {
        return (
            `<h1>Its graeater also</h1>`
            )
    }}
  `;
})
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
</div>

<button id="btn">
Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do it using the Conditional (ternary) operator like so.

```
${x > 3 ? '<h1>It's greater than 3</h1>' : '<h1>It's less than 3</h1>'}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: I know, but I want to do if statement, as I said, this is exactly not my code, it is an example

Comment: We can't do all if statement logics using ternary operator

Comment: what conditional logic do you wanna do?

Comment: @burningalc, there could be lot, but for now, I want to do the one I shown using if statement inside of that

Comment: I think we will need a more concrete example of what you want to do because so far, the question can be handled by the ternary operator if you would just like to return a string based on the condition. I would just not include the condition inside template literals for anything more complex than that to increase the readability of your code.

Comment: What I posted is the simpler way to do it, its effectively the same as an if statement, just written more cleanly.  If theres some reason you have to use an if statement, you could just make a function in the template literal, and put your if statement and return in that function.

Comment: @burningalc, my question was not for specific this question, I want to add logics inside the template literals, more complex, which I believe would be done only using if else statement, including else if or maybe switch statement

Comment: Is there any example you can further provide for this question? @Travis's suggestion on extracting the logic into a separate function and include it into template literals may be what you are looking for, but again, I would discourage adding complex logics into it since you are writing *javascript*, not *template literals*

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ternary operator or && operator
Like this :

```
       main.innerHTML = `
         <h2>First</h2> 
         ${x>3?'<h1>Its greater also</h1>':""}
      `;
```

or

```
main.innerHTML = `
        <h2>First</h2> 
        ${x>3&&'<h1>Its greater also</h1>'}
      `;
```

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let x = 4;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //main.innerHTML = `
    //<h2>First</h2> 
    //${x>3?'<h1>Its greater also</h1>':""}
  //`;
   
    main.innerHTML = `
    <h2>First</h2> 
    ${x>3&&'<h1>Its greater also</h1>'}
  `;
})
```

```html
<div id="main">
  
</div>

<button id="btn">
Click
</button>
```

Comment: you can also use `&&` so that you won't need the extra `else` clause if that is just to return an empty string

Comment: Question was for if statement, not ternary operator?

Comment: We cannot use if statement inside string literal .